# @Autowired equivalent in Spring.net

Tags: c#, spring.net

Is there an `[Autowired]` attribute in Spring.net for C# that would work like the Java `@Autowired` annotation?

If not, is there any other way to specify that a field should be autowired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowiring [is supported](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-autowire) to some extent, but it is not nearly as advanced as other IOC containers for .Net.

You might also be interested in the [CodeConfig](http://springframework.net/codeconfig/) project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/kirov-opensource/NAutowired/blob/master/README.md

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class FooController : ControllerBase {

    //Use Autowired injection.
    [Autowired]
    private readonly FooService fooService;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get() {
      return fooService == null ? "failure" : "success";
    }
  }
```